# How to constrain keyclicks to digits only, before they are seen in a Windows Foms TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-office, vsto, office-addins

My application asks for a number, which should be constrained to:

- Positive integer
- Cannot have leading zeros
- 3-digit maximum

  [This is what my dialog looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao94W.png)

I believe I found the proper way to implement most of the requirements, by using the `TextChanged` `WinForms` event.

The part where I need help is in preventing any non-digit keystroke from being seen, even from a fraction of a second. Some sort of echo cancellation/replacement is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [NumericUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/numericupdown-control-windows-forms) control or a [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control (a MSDN docs [Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-working-with-the-maskedtextbox-control) on its use), or maybe a Custom one, like this [CodeProject MaskedEdit](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273/Masked-Edit-Control) control or this other: [FlexMaskEditBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4037/FlexMaskEditBox-a-masked-edit-control).

Here's a *manual* implementation, related to your question:

First thing, set your `TextBox` [`MaxLenght`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.MaxLength);k(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) property to `3`, so it will limit the input to max 3 numbers.

Filter the user Keypress to only accept Digits and BackSpace:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back & !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Make sure that a `Keys.D0` is not inserted in first position:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D0)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 || textBox1.SelectionStart == 0)
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Anti-Paste: refuses sudden changes to the `TextBox` text if the inserted text can't be translated to an `Integer` number.
Removes `0`s in the wrong position and other non-digit chars:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(1);
        else
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int Number))
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Being a properly educated professional, I stay away from BASIC and derivatives. I use the modern, Microsoft recommended programming language: C#

Comment: Jimi: There is something wrong with your HowManyItems_KeyDown() code: zeros in any position are ignored. Will double check. Thanks!

Comment: @Travis Banger  The `KeyDown` event code prevents the insertion of a `0` in the first position or if the `TextBox.Text` is empty. Inserting it in any other position is accepted. The `TextChanged` will test the string to see if an edit/paste caused a '0' to become the first char. If that happens, the `0`s is/are deleted (e.g. if you paste `001`, only `1` remains. If you paste `010`, you will get `10`).